# Writing data into json file using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

With the following python code :

```
    import fnmatch
    import os
    import json

    data = []
    for file in os.listdir('./images'):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.jpg'):
            data.append(file)
    with open('asd.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump({'data' : {"name": data}},f,sort_keys = True, indent = 4, 
            ensure_ascii = False)
```

I am getting the following json output in file `asd.json`:

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": [
            "got01.jpg",
            "got02.jpg"
        ]
    }
}
```

But I want my json output in `asd.json` as :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "got01.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "got02.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you suggest a better approach to get the output in desired structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`json.dump({'data' : [{"name": x} for x in data]},f,sort_keys = True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)`

Full code:

```
import fnmatch
import os
import json

data = []
for file in os.listdir('./images'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.jpg'):
        data.append(file)
with open('asd.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump({'data' : [{"name": x} for x in data]},f,sort_keys = True, indent = 4, 
        ensure_ascii = False)
```

Comment: check the curly brackets in `json.dump({'data' : [{"name": x} for x in data],f,sort_keys = True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)`

Comment: Yes, I have fixed it now.